# How to set column according to values of two other columns?

Tags: pandas

I have a dictionary of totals:

```
totals = {('china', 1990): 12345, ('china', 1999): 6789, ('mexico', 1989): 98765}
```

and a dataframe `df`:

```
country   year
china     1990
china     1999
mexico    1989
....
```

I would like to add a new column of `totals` according to the dictionary above. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
df['total'] = df[['country', 'year']].apply(lambda x: totals[x])
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First idea is use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) by `MultiIndex` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['total'] = df.set_index(['country', 'year']).index.map(totals)
```

Or create `Series` and use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.Series(totals, name='total'), on=['country', 'year'])
```

---

```
print (df)
  country  year  total
0   china  1990  12345
1   china  1999   6789
2  mexico  1989  98765
```